# Rotating particles around a mouse with an offset in canvas

Tags: html, animation, canvas

Basically, I want to rotate some particles with an offset from the mouse cursor and therefore form them in a ring shape around it:

[image]

All suggestions on how to achieve this is more then welcome!

Comment: Any code you have tried to create this is more than welcome!

Comment: Hakim El Hattab did some neat particle physics demos using html canvas.  Here's one of his demos that's on-point to your question. It illustrates particles orbiting around gravitational wells:  http://hakim.se/experiments/html5/magnetic/02/